# как передать JSON-параметры гугл-картам?

Tags: json, google-maps-api

Есть фрэйм с картой гугла:

```
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=myapikey&q=чортегде" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

И есть инструмент настройки внешнего вида карт: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/
в котором я получил, скажем, `JSON` настройки вида:

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#6793d3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Куда их деть? Много где говорится, что этому `GoogleAPI` можно передать `JSON` параметры. Копал у гугла - там в примерах опять же только сам `json` находил, а как его передать в `embed-frame` - нет.

хелп

Comment: В iframe это не засунуть. Вам нужно создать карту через API. Начните читать отсюда https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=ru

Answer (score 1):

Согласно **[этой статье Карты Гугл](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/importing_data)**, вы импортируете ваш json в карту Гугл с этим кодом:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8,-187.3),
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        // Create a <script> tag and set the USGS URL as the source.
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        // This example uses a local copy of the GeoJSON stored at
        // http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojsonp
        script.src = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/json/earthquake_GeoJSONP.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      }

      // Loop through the results array and place a marker for each
      // set of coordinates.
      window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
          var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1],coords[0]);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

И далее, уже созданную карту Гугл, вы устанавливаете в ваш iframe, но не json, который импортируется в карту.

Comment: все-таки вопрос был скорее про стили, чем про javascript, больше бы подошла ссылка на пример https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?hl=ru